# Rebooting a device when adb is connected over tcpip

Tags: android, tcp, adb, reboot

I have connected an android device over tcpip using `adb connect <ipaddress>`. I am able perfrom all operations of adb on this devices.

However when I issues a command `adb -s <ip>:5555 reboot`, I see that prompt simply hangs and reboot is not being performed on the devices.

Is this a known limitation of adb over tcpip?
Are there any other ways to issue reboot commands in such cases?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Command `adb -s :5555 reboot` is **incorrect**, `adb -s <IP Address>:<5555> reboot` is **correct**.

If your device IP is `172.16.7.123`, use the following.

```
$ adb connect 172.16.7.123
```

Lets say your list of devices show the following

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
172.16.7.123:5555   device
0554e0700a67240d    device
```

The correct way to reboot the device using `adb` is

```
$ adb -s 172.16.7.123:5555 reboot
```

After issuing the above command, your prompt will hang since the `adbd` daemon is killed on the device.

To return it to normal, use `adb disconnect 172.16.7.123` on another prompt and it will return to normal.

Comment: besides forking another terminal's prompt to do adb disconnect , is ti achievable in the same prompt.